# Stop using WSUS on Client machines

Tags: wsus

I have a client that runs Windows SBS 2008 including WSUS service.
As the disk space runs out way to often and bandwith isn't a problem he asked me to help.

As I don't know SBS well and the customer is a friend (normally don't do such services :)):

- how is it possible to configure the SBS that way that all windwos 7 client use original windowsudpate.microsoft.com service again instead of using the SBS? Or do I just simple remove the client computer from the client service list which can be found in wsus manager?
- can I just stop the service WSUS after and remove the downloaded data?

Tried to find here or google any tutorials but the only stuff I can find is tp make disk space (remove not needed files), but not how to stop use WSUS.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a Group Policy Object that is configuring the [Specify Intranet Microsoft Update Service Location](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720539%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) setting. This is what is pointing the client machines to the internal WSUS server. Remove the setting to cause the clients to retrieve their updates directly from Windows Update.

If you don't want WSUS to be used at all then you can just remove the role from the server.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches of how updates are managed through WSUS: server-side and client-side targeting.

In your case, client-side targeting is used, which involves configuring group policy for WSUS clients.

In GPO, you configure which update resource to use, i.e. windowsudpate.microsoft.com or local WSUS server.

So, what you need to do is to edit GPO and change settings on WSUS server(configure it not to store updates locally >[Configure WSUS server settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720523%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)).

Hope, this article is helpful: [Configure WSUS-clients settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720520%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)